# AGAL Opcode mul and dp4

Tags: actionscript-3, agal

I am trying to dive into code AGAL and have some questions which are interesting for me.

The first question is about opcodes `mul` and `dp4`
If I am right, mul does the following

```
mul ft0, ft0, ft5 means ft0 = ft0 * ft5 which in fact is ft0.r*ft5.r +ft0.g*ft5.g+ft0.b*ft5.b+ft0.a*ft5.a
```

`dp4 ft0, ft0, ft5` does the same as `mul`, but you can change an order by using another component order, for instance `ft0.argb`?
 Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No, you wrong. mil means
ft0 = ft0 * ft5 = [ft0.r*ft5.r, ft0.g*ft5.g, ft0.b*ft5.b, ft0.a*ft5.a].
You get a vector.
dp4 returns scalar (ft0.r*ft5.r + ft0.g*ft5.g + ft0.b*ft5.b + ft0.a*ft5.a).
And yes, you can change an "order" - it's called swizzling.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was thinking that all registers are vectors, I had no idea they can be scalar. Could you please recommend a book or something regarding registers opcodes in AGAL?

Comment: Use this link as cheatsheet
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd6a006f2eb1dc31e-310b95831324724ec56-8000.html